# Inner Join from group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I have a table `countries` containing country codes and names:

```
name            code
FRANCE          FR
JAPAN           JP
```

And a table of page view stats `views`:

```
page_id    code            date    etc...
34         FR              2015-01-01
34         FR              2015-01-02
34         JP              2015-01-02
```

I'd like to output a list of all the countries that the page was seen in, but with the country name, so the results should say: `FRANCE, JAPAN`

I can easily get the list of country codes that it runs in:

```
SELECT code FROM views WHERE page_id = 34 GROUP BY code;
```

But mapping them across to the names in the countries table is the hard bit. Any ideas?

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT
    countries.name as name_from_countries,
FROM
    countries
INNER JOIN name_from_countries ON countries.code = views.code
WHERE
    views.page_id = 34
GROUP BY
    views.code
```

Comment: Is there a specific DBMS you're using?

Comment: I'm using postgres/amazon redshift :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need GROUP BY here. Just use DISTINCT.

```
SELECT DISTINCT countries.name as name_from_countries
FROM countries
INNER JOIN views ON countries.code = views.code
WHERE
    views.page_id = 34
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for introducing me to `distinct`! Will accept in a minute or two

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `countries.name` to your `GROUP BY` - I'm assuming you have some aggregates here:

```
SELECT v.code, c.name AS name_from_countries
  FROM views v INNER JOIN countries c
    ON v.code = c.code
 WHERE v.page_id = 34
 GROUP BY v.code, c.name;
```

If you don't have any aggregates (e.g., `COUNT(*)`), then you can get a list of countries with at least one view as follows:

```
SELECT c.code, c.name AS name_from_countries
  FROM countries c
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM views v
                 WHERE v.code = c.code
                   AND v.page_id = 34 );
```